# Equation of parabola

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to reduce the following equation by first rotating then translating the axes.

The equation is $$ x^{2}+4xy+4y^{2}+12x-6y=0. $$

I am not sure where to even begin with this problem.

Comment: Have you tried anything? You should at least give us a little bit of background.

Comment: No I havent because I do not know where to begin to tackle this problem

Comment: OK, but at least tell us what you've studied so far so we know how to guide you.

Comment: I have two equations:

Comment: x= x' cos(theta)-y'sin(theta) and y=x'sin(theta) +y'cos(theta)

Comment: and i know that tan2(theta) is b/(a-c)

Answer (score 1):

Suspect this is a homework problem. Here is what you do. Pick some angle $t$ (in your comments, likely $\theta$). Rotate your equation by switching to coordinates $u,v$ where $x = u\cos t + v \sin t$ and $y = - u \sin t + v \cos t$. Make substitutions and then pick $t$ in such a way that the mixed term $uv$ goes away (i.e. its coefficient becomes 0). Then you end up with something like
$$
Au^2 + Cv^2 + Du + Ev + F = 0
$$
where both $u$- and $v$-squares can be separately completed.